# How to get the length/number of objects in JSON

Tags: jquery

```
{"vegitable":[
    {
        "name": "tomato",
        "price": "$5.95"
    },
]},
{"fruit":[
    {
        "name": "orange",
        "price": "$7.95"
    },
]}
```

Both the objects are in one Json file. I would like to get the length of the objects in a variable using jquery, I mean vegitable is 1 object and fruit is another object.

```
Var lengthofJson = ??? //what should I put here?? 
Console.log(lengthofJson)  //result is 2
```

Comment: What you are showing is not valid JSON so it's impossible for us to provide a suggestion. Either fix your example how it really is, or if your data is really broken then the answer is: There is no standard way.

Comment: Look at here: https://jsfiddle.net/tjLbeacm/8/

Comment: Thank you I'll correct my JSON

Answer (score 0):

If your array should look like this then you can get Length of your json using this code

```js
var json = {
  "vegitable": [{
    "name": "tomato",
    "price": "$5.95"
  }],

  "fruit": [{
    "name": "orange",
    "price": "$7.95"
  }]
}
console.log(Object.keys(json).length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your JSON object,

```
 x = {
    "vegitable":[
        {
            "name": "tomato",
            "price": "$5.95"
        },
    ],
    "fruit":[
        {
            "name": "orange",
            "price": "$7.95"
        },
    ]
    }
```

then you could find the length like

```
Object.keys(x).length
```

which will give you result 2.